# Execute a method before saving a model in Play Framework 1.x

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

How do I execute a method just before saving a model?

Like for example hashing passwords in a User Model.

`@Before` annotation does not seem to exist for models.

I am using PlayFramework 1.2.x

PS : I plan on using it with the CRUD Module.

Comment: Are you looking for JPA's @PrePersist kind of callbacks ?

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM : Ya kind of, But I don't need something that complicated. Just execute a method and then save .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the collection of `Pre*` annotations in JPA. For example [`PrePersist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) and [`PreUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html).

In your model, just stick  the annotation you need onto the method that you want to invoke.

```
@PrePersist
public void hashPassword(){
    // do stuff
}
```

---

Another option might be [to override the `save()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417647/save-and-save-models-methods-in-playframework/5419083#5419083) for the particular model, but I wouldn't do that unless it's completely necessary. I would stick to the JPA APIs if they offer a solution, but that is just my opinion.

Comment: Actually I did some research after you mentioned overriding `save()`, As it turns out overriding `save()` is not such a bad Idea because it calls `_save()` which contains the actual business logic , refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5419083/492561

Comment: Nice. I'll add the link to my answer for completeness.